# How to add a conditional test step in SoapUI?

Tags: groovy, automation, soapui

I have a template which I use to create my test cases. Say I have a test step Step1 and it has two assertions inside that. I need to check if that test step passes it should go to Step2 or goto Step3. I am trying to use Groovy script to check the status of the assertion message from Step1. The assertions coming from the template to Step1 are "Contains" and "Valid"

Answer (score 0):

I have not used it before but here you have: [Conditional Goto](https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/teststep-reference/conditional-goto/conditional-goto.html)

In my soapUI project I needed to call (in all my TestCase) a test Step1 (authentication) before continue with the others test. So I added a "reference" to this Step1 in all my TestCases and it works ok for me.

> Any number of TestSteps can be added to a TestCase; add them by
>   either right clicking in the TestStep list and selecting add/insert or
>   by pressing the corresponding TestStep button in the TestCase window

[Working with TestSteps](https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/working-with-teststeps.html)